# Need help understanding logic

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper, svelte-store

Could someone please explain to me how this line works:
https://github.com/sveltejs/realworld/blob/master/src/routes/login/index.svelte#L13

`const response = await post(`auth/login`, { email, password });`

`post` is being called from `utils.js`, which is this:

utils.js

```
export function post(endpoint, data) {
    return fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(r => r.json());
}
```

So the function enters here, and then fetches the endpoint provided, which was `auth/login`.

This confuses me because`auth/login` is not an endpoint, it's a file that exports a function, under `auth/login.js`. Does this second post function in `auth/login.js` get called automatically? I am unsure where this `(req, res)` gets passed in as well, since we are just fetching this file from above and not passing any arguments.

auth/login.js

```
import * as api from 'api.js';

export function post(req, res) {
    const user = req.body;

    api.post('users/login', { user }).then(response => {
        if (response.user) req.session.user = response.user;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}
```

This is where the user is being set in a cookie, which my code isn't currently doing, and the session is lost upon refresh. I am trying to understand how to persist sessions in Sapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is making a call to a relative path:
const response = await post(`auth/login`, { email, password });

So the url that fetch is calling is something like : http://yourdomain.com/auth/login

According to the docs, what happens when a route ending in .js is called is that Sapper looks for a function with the name of the HTTP request method on that file.
More info here : sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Server_routes

Comment: I did post the code to `auth/login`. That file is the file that gets called.

Comment: Calling a file is different than fetching a file and than calling one of the methods of that file. If your routing logic makes all fetch calls to "auth/login" to call your file (that is, importing login.js at runtime) nothing will happen. If it makes all fetch calls to access login.js as a public resource, then the plain .js file will be returned. If it makes all fetch calls to run the post function inside login.js then the logic and result have to be explicit in your code. That's why I put that everything depends on your routing logic (your router)

Comment: The routing is file based. I'm using Sapper, and that repo I linked is a working example. I am still confused how this actually works. The link is to the local file 'auth/login', which I linked above, or can be found in the linked repo. When `auth/login` gets called, somehow the `post` function is called, and I don't understand how because I don't work in node and this is all relatively new to me.

Comment: Ok I read Sapper documentation and on the routing section it says that .js files on the routes folder are processed as Server Routes, and they export functions corresponding to HTTP methods, so this is the third case (calling one of the methods of that file), but the routing logic is inside the framework libraries: https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Server_routes